# With Pandas json_normalize how can I select only some of the dictionary fields?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas json_normalize to import the cik, entityName, end, fp, and val fields from this json:

```
{   "cik": 320193,   "entityName": "Apple Inc.",   "facts": {
    "dei": {
      "EntityCommonStockSharesOutstanding": {
        "label": "Entity Common Stock, Shares Outstanding",
        "units": {
          "shares": [
            {
              "end": "2023-07-21",
              "val": 15634232000,
              "accn": "0000320193-23-000077",
              "fy": 2023,
              "fp": "Q3",
              "form": "10-Q",
              "filed": "2023-08-04",
              "frame": "CY2023Q2I"
            },
            {
              "end": "2023-10-20",
              "val": 15552752000,
              "accn": "0000320193-23-000106",
              "fy": 2023,
              "fp": "FY",
              "form": "10-K",
              "filed": "2023-11-03",
              "frame": "CY2023Q3I"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

I would like the end result to look like this:

```
          end          val    fy  fp  cik     entityName
0  2023-07-21  15634232000  2023  Q3  320193  Apple Inc.
1  2023-10-20  15552752000  2023  FY  20320193  Apple Inc.
```

So far I have this code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, record_path=['facts', 'dei', 
    'EntityCommonStockSharesOutstanding', 'units', 'shares'], 
    meta=['cik', 'entityName'])
```

However, this code will normalize all fields in the shares list.

```
          end          val                  accn    fy  fp  form       filed      frame     cik  entityName
0  2023-07-21  15634232000  0000320193-23-000077  2023  Q3  10-Q  2023-08-04  CY2023Q2I  320193  Apple Inc.
1  2023-10-20  15552752000  0000320193-23-000106  2023  FY  10-K  2023-11-03  CY2023Q3I  320193  Apple Inc.
```

I know that I can delete the columns that I don't want.  Is there a cleaner way I can do this by just specifying the fields I care about as part of the json_normalize call?

Answer (score 0):

The json input functions don't have a parameter to selectively import fields.

You can just drop the columns after you've read the dataframe:

By the name of columns you don't want:

```
badcolumns = ['accn','form','filed','frame']
df = df.drop(columns=badcolumns)
```

or by any column that isn't in a list of ones that you do want:

```
goodcolumns = ['end','val','fy','fp','cik','entityName']
df = df.drop(columns=[col for col in df.columns if col not in goodcolumns])
```